# get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Tags: python, selenium

i keep getting error of "get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'" when running following code

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

def get_results(search_term):
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome
    browser.get(url)
    search_box = browser.find_element_by_class_name('gLFyf gsfi')
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    try:
        links = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//ol[@class="web_regular_results"]//h3//a')
    except:
        links = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//h3//a')
    results = []
    for link in links :
        href = link.get_attribute('href')
        print(href)
        results.append(href)
    browser.close()
    return results

get_results('dog')
```

the code is supposed to return search results of 'dog' from google, but gets stuck on

```
browser.get(url)
```

all help is appreciated

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is in the assignment of browser, `browser = webdriver.Chrome`. It needs to be `browser = webdriver.Chrome()`.

In your code you are not assigning an instance of the chrome webdriver to browser, but the class itself. Thus when you call `def get(self, url)`, your url parameter gets assigned to `self` and the argument `url` is not supplied, hence the positional argument error.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify a bit of your code.
Change the import statement:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Also, you need to create chrome driver instance and provide the path of chromedriver jar file.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
```